# How to avoid multiple flat if conditions in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, methods

Consider the snippet:

```
def check_conditions(range_of_numbers):
#method returns a list containing messages 
    list1 = []
    if condition1:
       list1.append("message1")
    if condition2:
       list1.append("message2")
    if condition3:
       list1.append("message3")
    try:
       for i in range_of_numbers:
           int(i)
    except ValueError:
        list1.append("message4")
    return message
```

I want to have a list in the with messages only if the conditions were satisfied. I do not use multiple if's since it adds on to the code complexity and every time a new parameter is added I would end up adding a new if condition.

Comment: Do you want to create these conditions dynamically? Because if not, then your current way of writing them is readable and totally fine, i would not change it.

Comment: Have a look at [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just loop on the condition/message couples for instance:

```
for condition,message in ((condition1,"message1"),(condition2,"message2"),(condition3,"message3")):
    if condition:
       list1.append(message)
```

if the conditions are exclusive, consider adding a `break` if one condition matches.

list comprehension version (more "pythonic" but not possible to break on first condition match, though):

```
list1 = [message for condition,message in ((condition1,"message1"),(condition2,"message2"),(condition3,"message3")) if condition]
```

Comment: Why not put conditions and messages in lists and zip over them?

Comment: yes, that also works. But since OP code hardcodes the couples, a hardcoded list of tuples is better than zipping 2 hardcoded lists. If the data comes in 2 lists it's different.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement of Jean-FrançoisFabre.

#### All conditions are satisfied

```
tmp = [message for condition, message in ((condition1, "message1"),
       (condition2, "message2"),(condition3, "message3")) if condition]
```

#### Conditions are exclusive

```
tmp = next((message for condition, message in ((condition1, "message1"),         
           (condition2, "message2"), (condition3, "message3")) if condition), None)
```